# Julia set algorithm

Tags: java, math, mandelbrot

I have a Mandelbrot set generator:

```
private int calculateMandel(double positionX, double positionY) {
    int valueOne = 0;
    double complexReal = 0.0;
    double complexImaginery = 0.0;
    double complexRealSquare = 0.0;
    double complexImaginerySquare = 0.0;

    while (valueOne < MAX && complexRealSquare + complexImaginerySquare < 4.0) {
        complexImaginery = 2.0 * complexReal * complexImaginery + positionY;
        complexReal = complexRealSquare - complexImaginerySquare + positionX;
        complexRealSquare = complexReal * complexReal;
        complexImaginerySquare = complexImaginery * complexImaginery;

        valueOne++;
    }

    return valueOne;
}
```

After modifying `complexReal` and `complexImaginery` to certain values at the beginning, somehow I cannot get the Julia set at the values.
What am I doing wrong? What would be the correct algorithm for generating Julia Set at a predefined certain point?

Comment: Add some sysouts and check where exactly the calculations are breaking down.

Comment: I think there is a similar pseudo code [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Escape_time_algorithm)

Comment: Please post the outer code that is calling calculateMandel. Also -- is valueOne your "escape velocity" from the complex plane, that is, how fast the complex number goes out of range? I am not certain how you're writing this, but you may want to pass the routine two complex numbers instead of two doubles. And I'm not sure that you should be adding positionX and positionY every time in the while loop. I think instead these should be initial states.

Comment: Java's an object-oriented language.  Why aren't you starting with a Complex number class?

Answer (score 0):

The iteration for a [Julia set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#Quadratic_polynomials) depends on *two* parameters: an initial value *z*<sub>0</sub> and a constant parameter *c*. Usually, the first is the position of the pixel you want to color, whereas the second is a parameter describing *which* Julia set you want to plot. So use the pixel position to initialize your complex variable, then add a fixed constant after each squaring. The way I read your question, you used these two the opposite way, with a fixed initialization but a position-dependent addition.